# Write back modified column into the same file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I am Writing a python code to read a csv file, then modify a selected column. Now I want to write back the column in same position. My code so far is

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('out.csv')
x = df['User Time']

def func(x):
    if (518400 < x) and (x < 604800):
        return x - 518400
    elif (432000 < x) and (x < 518400):
        return x - 432000
    elif (345600 < x) and (x < 432000):
        return x - 345600
    elif (259200 < x) and (x < 345600):
        return x - 259200
    elif (172800 < x) and (x < 259200):
        return x - 172800
    elif (86400 < x) and (x < 172800):
        return x - 86400
    else:
        return x

x = x.apply(func)

df.to_csv('out.csv')[:2]
```

Using [:2] because it's 2nd column of the file.

It's not working. Help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use assignment / copies unnecessarily. Here, you can simply modify a series within your dataframe and export the entire dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('out.csv')

def func(x):
    # your function logic

df['User Time'] = df['User Time'].apply(func)
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

You can't "just update a single column" with Pandas. The framework is built-around having rows and columns with meaning. When you use `pd.read_csv` all the columns are read into a dataframe in the order you see in the file, so you need not worry about losing data.

Comment: Thanks. It's working. But there is additional two new serial number column added. Can you suggest a way to remove them?

Comment: @ArijeetSinha, No, you will need to ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a [mcve]. Your data may be malformed.